# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes when browsing firefox or gnome

Tags: 22.04, ssd, browser

0

Having a problem for a few weeks now with ubuntu 22.04 gnome on 2 dell optiplex 7020 computers. for example: browsing youtube or twitter results in a total freeze within minutes. no other problems with video or music software or filemanager or gnome-terminal. Thought it would be a ssd problem but switching the ssd into the other pc (same model pc dell optiplex 7020) gives the same issue. switch off hardware acceleration in chrome doesnt solve the issue neither does the use of firefox solves it. a long test with memtest says the memory is also ok on both computers. tried different (also a new one) ssd disks. also bought few new sata cables, didnt help. i thought it would be a ssd issue but isnt, a new 500gb ssd samsung also freezes... also tried to use the vga video output instead of display-port, didnt help.

even after many updates (even regular kernel update) problem is still there. i cant find anything that looks similar on the web acording to this issue. Windows 10 seems to work flawless but got used to debian/ubuntu since 2010 so i hope there is a solution for this. Does this sounds as a known problem to anyone?

dell optiplex 7020 with 8 GB RAM
CPU intel 4590

AMD radeon R5 240 videocard

Kingston A400 SSD 480GB with Windows 10

new Samsung 870 EVO SSD 500GB with Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for Ubuntu 22.04:

- Download Firefox from Mozilla (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/linux/)
- Extract
- Run the file firefox-bin
- Turn off hardware acceleration
- Stop using snap version of Firefox

Every time just run firefox-bin. Make it your default browser. No crashes.

Answer (score 0):

same happened with chrome so it wasnt a firefox issue, i never use firefox
it was a problem with this specific type of dell computer of the videocard , i dont know, searched for it on the internet many times but couldnt find a solution.
in the meantime i bought another computer (hp prodesk 400 g5 SFF) problem solved...